# Где в предложении пунктуационная ошибка?

Tags: пунктуация

Качество топлива, в странах бывшего СНГ, низкое и даже высокая цена "премиум" сортов, ещё не гарантирует чистоту и соответствие стандарту.

Comment: Приведите высказывание полностью, а то оно на предложение  очень мало похоже.

Comment: Здесь нужна всего одна запятая (после "низкое") - остальные ошибочны.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Качество топлива  в странах бывшего СНГ низкое, и даже высокая цена "премиум" сортов ещё не гарантирует его чистоту и соответствие стандарту.**

Это сложносочиненное предложение, одна запятая перед союзом И. Остальные запятые не имеют грамматического обоснования.

*В странах бывшего СНГ* – необособленное обстоятельство, *цена не гарантирует* – предикативная основа второго предложения (подлежащее и сказуемое).